# How could I concatenate the "Repere Topo" to be in one single result

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here is my actual output from my query (using PostgreSQL DataBase)

```
SELECT includ, Article_Ref, Name, Quantite,Repere from MyTable order by Article_Ref
```

[image]

I want to group the last Column to get this kind of result the seperator would be a Space

[image]

Feel free to ask me any additional questions .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to concatenate the last column.  For this, I prefer arrays:

```
select includ, Article_Ref, Name, Quantite,
       array_agg(Repere)
from MyTable 
group by includ, Article_Ref, Name, Quantite;
```

If you prefer a string:

```
select includ, Article_Ref, Name, Quantite,
       string_agg(Repere, ' ')
from MyTable 
group by includ, Article_Ref, Name, Quantite;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gordon . I've used a string and it worked like a charm .